# Why does removing apps frees less memory compared to installing?

Tags: uninstall

Suppose I had installed ndiswrapper, then it shows

```
   Need to get 226 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 1,110 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

But when i remove it by purge command, It says

```
  After this operation, 76.8 kB disk space will be freed.
```

I am new to linux and learned a lot recently pls can someone explain?

Comment: it has to download the package for installing, and then install it.  There's two parts then - what's in the package, and the package for installing itself.

Comment: Things to consider: 1. the package contains more than what is installed. 2. the package is compressed and too small to be smaller when compressed. 3. the package also installed a library it does not remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a software you install it and the dependencies it needs, these are other software and libraries it needs to run, but when you remove it, you only remove the software you installed.

You can remove the dependencies (assuming they're not required by something else) with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Or in one step with the removal of the original package:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove ndiswrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

The way aptitude works, it gets a file that is "compressed" and packaged, besides that, the package itself, needs A LOT of dependencies to get it working right.

So, when you install a package and their dependencies, you get all of them.

this line:

```
 Need to get 226 kB of archives.
```

Is the package or number of packages you need to get that are "compressed" or packaged.

And this line

```
 After this operation, 1,110 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Are the space is going to occupy all of those dependencies "uncompressed" and installed.

When you remove a package, generally you remove only the package and their dependencies stay the same, ("unless you remove them as well").

So that's my explanation of the issue, hope it helps.